# Probability of five children in the same class having the same given name

Tags: probability, combinatorics

On baby-naming forums, prospective parents repeat some version of their Fear of Jennifer all the time: "I don't want my child to be one of 5 in his class with his name." Thing is, no name comes even close to that sort of popularity any more, and even at the height of the Jennifer craze, you didn't get five of them in a class. I would like some sort of answer for these parents of just how unlikely such a coincidence of name repetition would be.

Using the Social Security Administration's extensive baby-name data (https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/limits.html), can someone tell me how to figure out the chances of an elementary school class in the U.S. having five children with the same name? (For simplicity, by "same name" I mean same spelling, and by "school class" I mean all the kids were born in the same year.) I'm not specifying a class size, but it should definitely be greater than 4. :-)

Comment: Posts about baby names is a recurring theme on Andrew Gelman's blog. In none of the posts I found on his site does he discuss your specific question. He does link to a "baby name blog" where you might have more luck getting an answer.   http://andrewgelman.com/2005/09/07/baby_name_blog/

Comment: I think you may string something together using the multinomial distribution with probabilities of success of say, the first top twenty names extracted from census data such as [this](https://www.ssa.gov/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi).

Comment: Does the SSA provide data about the *number* of children born with a name? I'm only finding information about *ranks* which obviously discards some useful information.

Comment: @AntoniParellada That's a good find - but limiting to the top 20 will probably discard too much information: only 8% of males and 7.7% of females are represented!

Comment: @GeneralAbrial You know, on a second thought, since what the OP is after is some sort of proof that it is not frequent to have a bunch of kids with the same name in the same class, limiting the names to the most popular may actually strengthen the point - if the probability is low even with high frequency values, you may (?) be done...

Comment: @AntoniParellada I think the reality of the situation is even more subtle: since the US school system is highly segregated by income and race, I think the national statistics will have a poor correspondence to actual classrooms.

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe for my purposes, it'd be enough to consider the probability of having 5 children named Isabella in a first-grade classroom (birth year 2010). How do I figure that out?

Comment: When I was a student at a (small) primary school, we had three Johns in a very small class (I think boys and girls combined was only about 14). One year we combined with the year above to make one full-size class... and got a fourth John. Now John was pretty common then but not all *that* common. (In terms of the original issue, three would be nearly as annoying as five). The chance of a *particular* name being duplicated many times would be very low, but the chance *some* name appears multiple times will be far higher.

Comment: Isn't it the chance of a particular names' being duplicated that's relevant here? Surely parents aren't afraid their child will join a class having five children with the same name as each other, but rather that it'll join a class having four other children with the same name as it.

Comment: @Scortchi That looks like the correct interpretation based on the preliminaries to the question, but it's not the question that was (eventually) explicitly asked.  Indeed, if one is concerned that one's child might share a name with others, there is a simple non-statistical solution: give her a unique name.

Comment: Hello, my name is: Muhammad23z

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All data can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pm6BL3FopzSWTIGBR9X_SrvVK4RFBjp300OnSlSNRoU/edit?usp=sharing).  Each value in the table represents the probability that given a 25-person sample from that location and birth year, 5 of them will share a name.

**Method**: I used the [Binomial PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function) on on each name to find the probability that any given 25-person class would have 5 people who shared a name:

```
n = class size
k = 5,6,...,n 
p_i = (# of name[i]'s) / (total # of kids)
```

$$P_n(5+\ kids\ share\ name) = \sum_{\forall\ names}\sum_{k=5}^n{n \choose k}p_i^k(1-p_i)^{n-k} $$

For example, if there are 4,000,000 total kids, and 21,393 Emily's, then the probability that there are 5 Emily's in any given class with 25 students is Binomial(25, 5, 0.0053) = 0.0000002.  Summing over all names does not give an exact answer, because by the [Inclusion/Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability), we must also account for the possibility of having multiple groups of 5 people who share names.  However, since these probabilities are for all practical purposes nearly zero, I've assumed them to be negligible, and thus $P(\bigcup A_i) \approx \sum P(A_i)$.

**Update:** As many people pointed out, there is considerable variance over time, and between states.  So I ran the same program, on a STATE BY STATE basis, and over time.  Here are the results (nation-wide probability is red, individual states are black):

[image]

Interestingly, Vermont (my home state) has been consistently one of the most likely places for this to happen for the past several decades.

Comment: Any chance you could explain how you got these numbers? You don't need to dumb it down much -- I do have a bachelor's degree in math, and I know where to look stuff up -- but I'd really like to know the sort of reasoning that actually leads to probabilities (instead of daunted sighs).

Comment: I posted my method, hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! I think I actually understand now. (It _is_ an extension of the birthday problem/paradox, just with, um,  a bit more data crunching involved.)

Comment: This assumes that names are given *at random* with *the same probabilities*, what is simply *not true*. Also real-life experience shows that there is *much more* classes with kids having the same names then 1 in 200!

Comment: @Tim Not sure how closely you read my post, but the actual statistic is 1 in 200 classes with 100 students ought to have **FIVE** kids with the same name.

Comment: @Tim Also, you point out that names _are not_ randomly distributed, which is valid.  I just assumed that we could construct a 25 person class by taking a random sample from all 4 million children.  Of course in the real world, this is not entirely accurate, "since the US school system is highly segregated by income and race".  However, for the purposes of answering the OP's question, which seemed to be more anecdotal than anything, assuming we could just take a random 25-person sample seemed reasonable.

Comment: @DavidC so it seems that from your description is not totally clear where did you get the numbers... Also 5 kids in 200 100-person classes is pretty strange way of looking at this. Why not standard class (I guess you could assume some average size)? Why not start with calculating probability of two kids sharing name and comparing it with 5 kids?

Comment: @Tim 1. All of my numbers were derived with the formula in my description, under "Method".   2. OP did not specify class size, so I chose three arbitrary class sizes.  I'd guess 25 would be about average, but certainly most classes are smaller than 100.  3. Not sure what you mean by comparing the probability of two kids sharing a name with five kids.  I have no interest in pursuing this, however, but I encourage you to do your own research, if you are interested in the topic

Comment: The formula is vague: in particular, it does not specify the range of $k$ in the sum.  I find it difficult to come up with an interpretation that makes it correct.  Could you elaborate on it?

Comment: @DavidC two kids is a birthday paradox problem, then you can extend it to non-equal probabilities (that will differ for different names, what is worth mentioning), and then go to 5 kids. By this you start with a simple suboptimal model and then can compare it to something else. It is not clear how did you get "binomial pdf" for multiple thousands of different names with different probabilities and came up with a single number.

Comment: @whuber $k=5$.  This is written in the description.  There is no range. $k$ represents the number of kids with the same name.  For example, there are 4,000,000 total kids, and 21,393 Emily's.  So the probability that there are 5 Emily's in any given class with 25 students is Binomial(25, 5, 0.0053) = 0.0000002

Comment: @David, I understand your P(n) as the sum of each name's probablity being exact five times in the class with n children. I am not sure if this term is a probability, since it can become larger than one, am I wrong? Also, the question was for the probability a name being _at least_ five times in the class, not exact five times. The probability for each name is taken from the https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/limits.html "National data" source being relative count for each name, I guess.

Comment: (1) You need to include the possibility of *more* than five kids: that's why there needs to be a range.  (2) Did you combine the male and female counts of unisex names?  (3) How did you account for the rare names that simply are not listed in this table?

Comment: @whuber Thank you for pointing this out, I just re-ran the program to include the possibility of (1) and (2) from your comment, and the answers are the same as before.

Comment: @DavidC it is *impossible* that probability of exactly 5 kids sharing the name is the same as probability of at least five kids sharing name.

Comment: @Tim They are equal to at least the first two digits, as listed in the table

Comment: I get slightly different results, but they're close.  This isn't worth discussing, though, *because the geographic and temporal variation in the results is huge.*  The answer has changed by two orders of magnitude since 1910 and varies by an order of magnitude among states.  Since almost no elementary school class is drawn from the entire US, the model of random selection from the national names list is inappropriate.

Comment: @whuber Do you have any source for your claim that "geographic and temporal variation huge"?  Or is this just your assumption?

Comment: (1) Look at the other years in the national file you downloaded.  (2) Look at the state files available on the same site.

Comment: The point is that data from the past demonstrate the answers have varied over time and therefore are likely to vary, even among the different age cohorts currently in elementary school.  The geographic variation is profound and of immediate importance, because in the US almost all elementary education is public and *local.*  That such variation appears in the data shows these concerns are not merely hypothetical; and the very large amount of that variation, even at the state level, shows that any answer derived from your model (of random selection nationally) is unreliable.

Comment: @whuber: the time variance is _exactly the point_: it's not like it used to be, because baby names have become much, much more varied than they were in 1910 (or 1970). And the state-by-state data is also available from the same place, so I'm thinking of running the formula using a few small states in different parts of the country. I doubt the answer will substantially change.

Comment: @JPmiaou You are absolutely correct!  Since 1970, the probability of this event has diminished drastically. I've posted a new graph to show this

Comment: Yes, the graph of probabilities over time is dramatic: it began a steep decline by 1980.  But the state variation is very large indeed, as one would expect: names vary geographically and they cluster strongly by ethnicity, income, and other demographic factors. (+1 for your extended investigation into the state and time variation, BTW.)

Comment: Lovely graphs, @DavidC! It's interesting that Vermont is the least name-diverse place in the country. I wonder how much of that is due to its small population: are the other "high points" also small states?

Comment: @David C. Really interesting graphs. Thx :)

Comment: @David C: there used to be a table in your answer with a variety of class sizes and the corresponding probabilities, but it seems to have been edited out of the current version, and I can't figure out how to get it back. Since there's a fairly daunting amount of data crunching involved in generating those numbers, I think they should be added back in.

Comment: @JPmiaou I removed the table because it seemed to clutter up the answer, and because as whuber pointed out, the numbers were not very meaningful alone.  I added a link at the top of the post that has the complete set of data

Comment: @whuber. To be honest, I read the question again and thought about and I find, my answer is valid since a parent has a child with a given name. So the question was for the probability that a given name is at least five times in the class. So the parent should not worry about, according to this simple estimate based on one year's name distribution. Although, I like how this topic evolved :) Thx

Answer (score 0):

please see the following Python-script for Python2.

Answer is inspired by David C's answer.

My final answer would be, the probability of finding at least five Jacobs in one class, with Jacob being the most probable name according to the data from https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/limits.html "National Data" from 2006.

The probability is calculated according to a binomial distribution with Jacob-Probability being the probability of success.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import binom

data = pd.read_csv(r"yob2006.txt", header=None, names=["Name", "Sex", "Count"])

# count of children in the dataset:
sumCount = data.Count.sum()

# do calculation for every name:
for i, row in data.iterrows():
    # relative counts of each name being interpreted as probabily of occurrence
    data.loc[i, "probability"] = data.loc[i, "Count"]/float(sumCount)

    # Probabilites being five or more children with that name in a class of size n=25,50 or 100
    data.loc[i, "atleast5_class25"] = 1 - binom.cdf(4,25,data.loc[i, "probability"])
    data.loc[i, "atleast5_class50"] = 1 - binom.cdf(4,50,data.loc[i, "probability"])
    data.loc[i, "atleast5_class100"] = 1 - binom.cdf(4,100,data.loc[i, "probability"])

maxP25 = data["atleast5_class25"].max()
maxP50 = data["atleast5_class50"].max()
maxP100 = data["atleast5_class100"].max()

print ("""Max. probability for at least five kids with same name out of 25: {:.2} for name {}"""
   .format(maxP25, data.loc[data.atleast5_class25==maxP25,"Name"].values[0]))
print
print ("""Max. probability for at least five kids with same name out of 50: {:.2} for name {}, of course."""
   .format(maxP50, data.loc[data.atleast5_class50==maxP50,"Name"].values[0]))
print
print ("""Max. probability for at least five kids with same name out of 100: {:.2} for name {}, of course."""
   .format(maxP100, data.loc[data.atleast5_class100==maxP100,"Name"].values[0]))
```

Max. probability for at least five 
kids with same name out of 25: 4.7e-07 for name Jacob

Max. probability for at least five
kids with same name out of 50: 1.6e-05 for name Jacob, of course.

Max. probability for at least five 
kids with same name out of 100: 0.00045 for name Jacob, of course.

By a factor of 10 same result as David C's. Thanks.
(My answer does not sum all the names, should may be discussed)

Comment: This answer does not appear to address the question of the chance that *some* name appears five or more times in a classroom.

Comment: Uhmm, I thought finding one Jacob in a class is most probable. So finding at least five Jacobs in one class is also more probable than any other name, isn't it? So my conclusion would be, no one should worry about finding his or hers kids name five times in a class, even if the kid is called Jacob. In my optinion, the sum over all names is not appropriate. Please discuss. Thx

Comment: @feinmann I believe that taking the sum over all names is appropriate because the probability of having two or more sets of 5 people with the same name in one class is nearly zero, and is negligible for all practical purposes.  That is, according to the [Inclusion/Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle#In_probability), if we disregard this possibility, then $P(\bigcup A_i) \approx \sum P(A_i)$

Comment: I realize the question changes from the beginning of the original post to the end.  At the end though, there is a clear statement: "can someone tell me how to figure out the chances of an elementary school class in the U.S. having five children with the same name?"  Your post answers a different question.  @DavidC We need to take care with this approximation, because in other datasets (such as for names in 1910, when almost all children were named either John or Mary) it gives wildly incorrect values.

Comment: @whuber I think I answer the question: "What is a simple upper estimate for the chance of having at least five kids with the same name in the class." Do you agree?

Comment: @David C: I really have to think this thru, please. Thx :)

Comment: No, you haven't answered the question as you just formulated it.  The chance that *some* name will appear five or more times is much greater than the maximum chance that a *given* name will appear five or more times.

Comment: As @whuber points out, "5 Jacobs" is a weaker argument than "5 of some name", but it may be useful in baby name discussions anyway: "Here's the probability of five kids with the most popular name. You're not using the most popular name, so your probability is even less."

Comment: @JPmiaou Thank you. That is what I thought of. But please, help me out. What is the probability that "some" name is at least five times in a class. Is it really the sum of all single-name-probabilities? Thx

Comment: It's not *exactly*, because the possibilities aren't mutually exclusive: you could have 5 or more Thomases *and* 5  or more Richards (*and* perhaps even 5 or more Henrys) in a single class. So it's an upper bound. @DavidC argues in a comment here that such events have negligible probability.